# 5 events of reoxygenation (in tumour cells)

Tags: cancer, radiology

I was asked this question in a seminar ,while I have understood the basic process ,I  could not find specific mention of any such "events" in the books I referred to(Perez and Brady;Hall) or on the internet.So ,what are the 5 events?

Comment: Hi atilla, welcome to Medical Sciences. It would help users to answer your question if you provided additional details. "Some person asked me something in a seminar is very" challenging to help with.

Comment: This is pretty far outside my wheelhouse, but from what you've written here it seems like these "5 events" are *one person's way to structure a topic*. A bit like if you were writing a class paper on why Shakespeare is the best playwright, you might start out by alluding that you're going to talk about 5 ways Shakespeare is the best, and then spend a paragraph discussing each of those ways before returning to summarize it all. If you were asked this out of the blue, I'd respond with a request for clarification. If you're in a course, I'd expect you find the answer in the course text(s).

Comment: I typed *reoxygenation tumor five* into PubMed and learned there's something called "5 R's of radiobiology" which are "[Reoxygenation, DNA repair, radiosensitivity, redistribution in the cell cycle and repopulation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28905672/)" or "[reassortment, repair, reoxygenation, repopulation, radiosensitivity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5251326/)".  This doesn't answer your question properly, but I wonder if that's what they actually meant?